# NgForm.patchValue is not working in ngOnInIt but working fine when called from in click handler

Tags: angular

`NgForm.patchValue` is not working in `ngOnInIt` but working fine when called from in click handler. I have tried `ngZone` or calling `.patchValue()` from `ngAfterViewInit` but no success.

[Stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ltast)

**html**

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input type="text" name="test" ngModel>
</form>

<button (click)="click()">Click me</button>
```

**ts:**

```
 @ViewChild('f') f:NgForm;
  constructor(private zone: NgZone){}

  ngOnInit(){
   this.f.form.patchValue({test:123});
   //this.f.form.updateValueAndValidity();
   // this.zone.run(()=>{
   //   this.f.form.patchValue({test:123});
   // })
  }
  click(){
    this.f.form.patchValue({test:123})
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // this.f.form.patchValue({test:123})
  }
```

Comment: Consider using a timeout : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctpwrq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thanks tha work. Can you tell why so?

Comment: Simply because you don't hook on the right events. For instance, it also works on [`ngAfterContentChecked`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v3kbup?file=src/app/app.component.ts) (but you didn't seem to have tested it, so I assumed you didn't know it)

Comment: You could take a different approach and use `formGroup` instead. That way you don't need a timeout. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5uvpqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

Angular FormGroup has method such as patchValue().

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">

 <input formControlName="first">
 <input formControlName="last">

</form>
```

in ts:

```
const form = new FormGroup({
   first: new FormControl(),
   last: new FormControl()
});
console.log(form.value);   // {first: null, last: null}

form.patchValue({first: 'Nancy'});
console.log(form.value);   // {first: 'Nancy', last: null}
```